# How to make ContentControl to get Focus by mouse pointer?

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I have the following page

```xml
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" Background="LightGray">
        <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Button"/>
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas">
            <ContentControl x:Name="CC">
                <Border Width="100" Height="100" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" Background="White"/>
            </ContentControl>
            <ContentControl x:Name="CC2" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50">
                <Border Width="100" Height="100" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue" Background="White"/>
            </ContentControl>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I can navigate between the controls with keyboard(`Tab`) as expected : `Button->CC->CC2`, all of them generated the `GotFocus/LostFocus` event. But when I'm trying to navigate with mouse pointer , only the `Button` generated the `GotFocus/LostFocus` event. What I've missed ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. ContenControl inherits Control, so you could use [Control.Focus method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.focus?view=winrt-19041) to get focus in its PointPressed event.

In addition, ContentControl will lost focus after the PointerPressed event ends, in other words, GotFocus and LostFocus() will trigger continuously. So you need to set e.Handled = true to prevent LostFocus() from triggering.

For example:
in the constructor of Page

```cpp
FindName(L"CC").as<UIElement>().PointerPressed([](IInspectable sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs const& args){
  sender.as<Control>().Focus(FocusState::Programmatic);
  args.Handled(true);
});

FindName(L"CC2").as<UIElement>().PointerPressed([](IInspectable sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs const& args){
  sender.as<Control>().Focus(FocusState::Programmatic);
  args.Handled(true);
});
```

Comment: The question is tagged C++/WinRT. This answer uses some programming language that isn't C++.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm so sorry that I have ignored it, I will change it to c++ answer.